# RQ Scheduler queues task twice and stuck in loop running queued tasks

Tags: python, flask, redis, scheduler

I am trying to schedule a task on a Flask app with RQ-Scheduler but seem to have two issues that I can't find a solution for.

1. The task gets enqueued twice
2. There should be a 3-minute delay
   between tasks but there is no delay in the tasks, they just keep running infinitely once one task completes.

I've tried running it two different ways but neither solves the issues.

```
q = Queue(connection=conn)
s = Scheduler(queue=q,connection=conn)    

job = s.enqueue_in(timedelta(minutes=3),func=get_lines, args=("NFL",), repeat=None )
job = s.schedule(scheduled_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), func=get_lines, args=("NFL",), repeat=None, interval=300)
```

From another post I read that I needed to change how I run the Flask app to `app.run(use_reloader=False)` but that has not resolved the issues either.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!